# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setSelectedIndex: 4 out of bounds

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to make a game, but my code simply does not work and I have no idea why. I am a novice programmer with little experience, and have become very frustrated with my code. I have been trying to fix this problem, but to no avail. Please assist me.

```
public class hello {
    //Int's and things
    static JButton Play = new JButton("<PLAY>");
    static JFrame pane = new JFrame("CIrCUT 0.0.2");
    static JLabel Title = new JLabel("CIrCUT");
    static JLabel none = new JLabel(" ");
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10, 10, 10));
    static JButton Options = new JButton("<OPTIONS>");
    static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10, 10, 10));
    static String b[] = new String[3];
    static int panelLoct = 1;
    JComboBox optionlist = new JComboBox();

    void initialize() {
        b[0] = "High";
        b[1] = "Medium";
        b[2] = "Low";

        //title
        pane.setTitle("CIrCUT 0.0.2");
        //drop down
        optionlist .setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Option", "High", "Medium",  "Low"}));
        optionlist.setSelectedIndex(4);
        optionlist.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        //other pane-related things
        if (panelLoct == 1) {
            pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
            panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            pane.setSize(500, 500);
            pane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            panel.add(Title);
            panel.add(none);
            panel.add(Play);
            panel.add(Options);
            panel2.add(optionlist);
            Play.setSize(new Dimension(500, 450));
            pane.setLocation(500, 50);
            pane.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            pane.setContentPane(panel);
            pane.pack();
            pane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            pane.setContentPane(panel);
            OptionButtonHandler cbHandler = new OptionButtonHandler();
            Options.addActionListener(cbHandler);
            pane.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static class OptionButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pane.remove(panel);
            pane.add(panel2);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        cb.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        hello a = new hello();
        a.initialize();
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that the problem is the JComboBox, but whenever i remove it, i just get an error.

**EDIT**

here is the error

```
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at hello.initialize(hello.java:36)
at hello.main(hello.java:81)
```

Comment: If your code generates an exception, you'll want to post the actual exception stacktrace here as well as indicate for us which line throws the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add some option in optionlist then do  this optionlist.setSelectedIndex(4);

```
 JComboBox optionlist = new JComboBox();
 optionlist .setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Option", "Baby Ride Frame   s/s", "Baby Ring",  "Baby Tri Cycle Frame", "Baby Tri Cycle Frame D/Seat"}));
 optionlist.setSelectedIndex(4);
```

Comment: don't pass the this just pass the instance of ur Listner OptionButtonHandler instance =new OptionButtonHandler();            optionlist.addActionListener(instance );                  or optionlist.addActionListener(new OptionButtonHandler());

Comment: this is current intance in case of u it is intance of hello. and hello is not an ActionListner.

Answer (score 5):

```
JComboBox optionlist = new JComboBox();
optionlist.setSelectedIndex(4);
```

This will cause an exception since you're setting the index of an ***empty*** JComboBox. Simply don't do this. Fill the combo box with items *before* selecting an index.

In fact, where do you add *any* items to the JComboBox?

Note that in the future if you have a question about an exception that your code generates, you'll want to post the actual exception stacktrace here as well as indicate for us which line throws the exception.

Comment: @hovercraft: The JComboBox is not empty at all. He is adding the elements using model.

Comment: @RamDuttShukla: come on now, please be more careful when stating such things such as looking at the edit history of the original post. If you did that, you'd see that the model code was added in an edit hours after the original question was posted. My answer was correct in light of his original question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Oh, that may be a reason. It was not to hurt you :)

Comment: ya he is adding elements but think that array index starts form 0 so he added 4 so index will be 0,1,2,3 and he is trying to fetch 4th one. which is not available.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the model of ComboBox that is having only 4 elements, so the maximum allowed index will be 3(as its 0,1,2,3). So if you are trying to set the selected index to 4th element you must set it 3 as follows :

```
optionlist .setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Option", "High", "Medium",  "Low"}));
    optionlist.setSelectedIndex(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem with eclipse. The error was "setSelctedIndex(0) out of bounds. I solved it by making sure all servers were running on eclipse. That includes mysql, apache and the tomcat server to test for webpages. If you are using eclipse then make sure all local server are on.

Answer (score 0):

That is Because your are trying to show that item which is not Available into the Array list. so make sure that what ever you are trying to show that is Available into the Array list remember that Arraylist is Starting from

```
JComboBox optionlist = new JComboBox();
optionlist.setSelectedIndex(4);
```

and you dont have 4th index. Even your combobox is empty so there is not available 4th one.
and or do this.

```
JComboBox optionlist = new JComboBox();
optionlist.setSelectedIndex(-1);
```